issue with snowflake merge into incremental_strategy in DBT
The problem I'm having
i try to make a merge into from a source to another table in snwoflake using dbt cloud
this is the DDL and the line that i insert  in snowflake

CREATE TABLE TRAV_DWH_DEV.TRAV_ISILOG.trav_test_macro (
    id INT,
    prenom STRING,
    age INT
);

INSERT INTO TRAV_DWH_DEV.TRAV_ISILOG.trav_test_macro (id, prenom, age) VALUES
(1, 'axel', 30),
(2, 'francois', 25),
(3, 'hafsa', 40);



CREATE TABLE TRAV_DWH_DEV.TRAV_ISILOG.trav_test_macro_silver (
    id INT,
    prenom STRING,
    age INT
);



INSERT INTO TRAV_DWH_DEV.TRAV_ISILOG.trav_test_macro_silver (id, prenom, age) VALUES
(1, 'axel', 30),
(2, 'francois', 25);




SELECT * FROM TRAV_DWH_DEV.TRAV_ISILOG.trav_test_macro_silver;


this is my code in dbt in the models folder
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        unique_key='ID',
        incremental_strategy='merge',
        dest_table='TRAV_DWH_DEV.TRAV_ISILOG.trav_test_macro_silver'
    )
}}

select * from {{ref('stg_trav__trav_test_macro')}}



when i click on preview i have the line from my source and when i click to compile i only have a select * statements.
but when i type dbt build the models is running without an issue but the new line from source is not add neither the update for francois (the age)
Where i'm wrong ?

I see you are using incremental materialisation , but you dont have any date column or event_timestamp column , how would you find the updated records  ?
